# My parents are Afghan

Tags: adjective-ending

My friend asked me a question today:

> Woher kommen deine Eltern?

and I wanted to answer

> My parents come from Afghanistan.

I know that the nationality in German for "Afghan" is *afghanisch* with     die Afghanin and der Afghane for the respective individuals.

I failed to find any source for when the people in concern are plural.

What happens in that instance? Do we add the plural ending to "afghanisch" i.e. *afghanische* or what happens?

I thought it would be

> Meine Eltern sind afghanische

but I'm not sure.

**EDIT** my other thought was

> Meine Eltern sind Afghanen.

but again I'm not too sure.

Comment: "Meine Eltern sind afghanische": note that even if this was the right way to express your parents' nationality, it would be "Meine Eltern sind afghanisch" without the e. Adjectives in final position (more precisely, _predicative_ adjectives) don't take endings.

Answer (score 16):

Your thought in the edit was correct: If you want to refer to multiple Afghans in German, the plural noun *Afghanen* is used. It comprises male and female individuals alike.

> Meine Eltern sind *Afghanen*.
>   
>   <sup>(My parents are Afghans.)</sup>

However, if you want to explicitly refer to female Afghans, the noun *Afghaninnen*, which is the plural of *Afghanin*, is used.

> Heute traf ich zwei *Afghaninnen*.
>   
>   <sup>(Today I met two Afghan women.)</sup>

The word *afghanisch* is an [adjective](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:afghanisch), which has to be declined appropriately. Its role is to modify noun phrases.

> Ich habe einen *afghanischen* Vater.
>   
>   <sup>(I have an Afghan father.)</sup>
>
> Ich habe eine *afghanische* Mutter.
>   
>   <sup>(I have an Afghan mother.)</sup>
>
> Ich habe ein *afghanisches* Patenkind.
>   
>   <sup>(I have an Afghan godchild.)</sup>
>
> Ich habe *afghanische* Eltern.
>   
>   <sup>(I have Afghan parents.)</sup>

---

**Addendum**

In case that, as user @McLovin believes, you really just wanted to know what *"My parents come from Afghanistan"* means in German, the answer is simply

> Meine Eltern kommen aus Afghanistan.

Comment: And, to add, an *Afghane* in common German speech is also the Afghan hound.

Comment: great! I hate to ask, but in the sentence "Meine Eltern sind Afghanen" is the "Afghanen" a plural *noun* that we use in this sentence?

Comment: @Janka, and I thought it is a kind of weed.

Comment: @BobSmith: It is, and that is the only reason why it starts with a capital letter (being a place name isn't relevant for that in German, as evidenced in the adjective "afghanisch").

Comment: I really don't get why this answer has so many upvotes as it does not answer the main question. He specifically wanted to know what "My parents come from Afghanistan." means in German and not what their nationality was.

Comment: @McLovin No, OP's specifically asking for the correct way of expressing the nationality. He is using the sentence "My parents come from Afghanistan" as the English expression of that.

Comment: @sgf The description of the question actually does not match with the answer OP wanted to give. I see OP is trying to describe it with nationality but if he wanted it to be answered this way, his provided answer would have been "My parents are afghan.". This is also something I would not expect as an answer in any conversation when asking where someones parents are from.

Comment: @McLovin: Für solche Fälle gibt es den Flag **not an answer**. Zudem kommt eine eigene Antwort in der Regel besser an, als ein neidischer Kommentar. Ob die dann aber mehr Upvotes verdient, steht auf einem anderen Blatt.

Comment: @McLovin "I know that the nationality in German for "Afghan" is afghanisch with die Afghanin and der Afghane for the respective individuals.
I failed to find any source for when the people in concern are plural. " That makes clear what the OP is after. "Meine Eltern sind Afghanen" is a flawless answer to "Woher kommen deine Eltern?".

Answer (score 10):

> Woher kommen deine Eltern?

There's no need to return a full sentence by repeating »Eltern« and »kommen«, the most simple (and probably most common) answer would be:

> Aus Afghanistan.

Some say just

> Afghanistan.

which is less polite, because one may get the impression that you want to kill the conversation instantly by giving a minimal answer.

Comment: Beim Sprachunterricht gilt aber das Mantra "im ganzen Satz!".

Comment: @userunknown Bei vielen schlechten Sprachlehrern ist es leider so, dass nur eine synthetische und normgerechte Sprache unterrichtet wird. Das ist vermutlich eine der wichtigsten Ursachen dafür, und in Deutschland leider sehr stark verbreitet, dass Schüler trotz vieler Jahre Sprachunterricht weder in der Lage sind die gelernte Sprache praxistauglich zu verstehen noch zu verwenden. Zum Glück waren meine Deutschlehrer nicht so, sonst hätte ich hier nicht schreiben können.

Answer (score 4):

Direct translation of your English sentence:

> Meine Eltern kommen aus Afghanistan.

That avoids all the hassle of finding out how the adjectives must be declinated.

Otherwise you can write:

> Meine Eltern sind afghanisch (*no -e*).

But:

> Ich habe afghanische Eltern.

*Don't ask me about the rules for this: I speak the language pretty well, but don't know much about the rules behind this, i.e. when to declinate or when to use the base form of the adjective*.

You can also write:

> Meine Eltern sind Afghanen.

or, if asked about only one parent:

> Meine Mutter ist Afghanin

*or*

> Mein Vater is Afghane.

Comment: I don't think anybody would really say that last sentence, would they?

Comment: Also, Meine Eltern sind afghanisch is grammatically correct, but people wouldn't say that. It sounds mildly pejorative to speak of people's ethnicitcy by a predicative adjective ("sind ...-isch").

Comment: @TonyK: why not? Ok, they won't say Afghanen, Afghanin and Afghane in one sentence. But you don't have to. This was just an example. Your either say *they are ...* **or** you say *Sie ist ...und er ist ...* (especially if they are not both from the same country).

Comment: @sgf: I don't find it pejorative at all! If someone would say *Meine Eltern sind niederländisch*, that would be perfectly fine with me (I am Dutch).

Comment: Well, they _are_ from the same country. So nobody would put it like that in real life.

Comment: @TonyK. Very likely not, indeed. But as example, it is good enough, IMO.

Comment: @sgf: Either that, or it's mistaken for meaning they follow Afghan customs or stereotypes (whichever those may be), rather than being Afghans by current or original nationality.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis "Meine Eltern sind niederländisch" also sounds slightly pejorative to me. It sounds as if you're actually saying "Meine Eltern sind sooo niederländisch." (Meaning all the clichés about Dutch people hold for them.) I think this is also what O.R. Mapper is getting at.

Comment: @sfg: Not to me, and I am niederländisch too. Even if someone would say about me "er ist soooo niederländisch" I would not see it as a slight.

Comment: Repeating like it is done in the last example would have a connotation of very strong emphasis (eg as an answer to someone who put your Afghan heritage in question), and could even come across offended or very patriotic.

Comment: @rackandboneman: <sigh> that "sentence" is merely a demonstration of the declinations, nothing else. I will rewrite the answer so I don't get any more unnecessary comments about that sentence. Of course one wouldn't say all these things at once: Afghanen, Afghanin, Afghane. You say the one that is appropriate.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: "Sie sind afghanische Afghanen aus Afghanistan.", correct? ;) I agree "... ist (sooo) niederländisch." doesn't sound pejorative to me, but that is mainly because there are no negative stereotypes (or rather, barely any stereotypes at all) connected to "niederländisch" here in Southern Germany. If someone said "... ist (sooo) schottisch.", I would be much more likely to assume the speaker means "stingy" rather than "generally clinging to Scottish customs" or similar.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: No negative stereotypes connected to the Dutch? Really? Just think of Dutch caravans blocking the fast lanes on German Autobahns. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Hm. I knew about the caravan thing, but it was more of an amusing "Those funny people take their caravans wherever they go." kind of thing in my perception rather than anything negative. YMMV if you actually like driving fast and are not happy to sort yourself into a lane of non-speeding vehicles that impose a reasonable and permanent speed to adapt to, of course.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: If you want negative gossip about the Dutch, ask the Belgians. <g>

Comment: I am not sure if "Sie sind afghanisch" und "Sie kommen aus Afghanistan" is actually the same thing (e.g. my wife is Irish, but she does not come from Ireland, her parents did). I would be curious if there is a rule for that.

Comment: @Eike: But if it is the same thing, then you can say both. So if they come from Afganistan, you can say either sentence. FWIW, my son is from Germany, but has the Dutch nationality, IOW, the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather say

> Meine Eltern sind aus Afghanistan.

then

> Meine Eltern sind Afghanen.

in German. Both are technically correct, but the first association the word `Afghane` might trigger in Germans is the dog and not the nationality.

Comment: Dem letzten Satz muss ich vehement widersprechen. In den letzten Jahren war Afghanistan aus vielerlei Gründen Thema in den Medien. Wollen Sie ernsthaft behaupten, deutsche Medienkonsumenten hätten zuallererst an Hunde gedacht? Zudem wusste ich bis gestern nicht einmal von der Hunderasse. Das mag eine Bildungslücke gewesen sein, doch vermutlich teile ich die mit vielen anderen Menschen.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I totally agree. But without this sentence this would be a solid answer worth upvoting.

Comment: @miep, I disagree. Just saying, _"I would rather do it like this"_ is not worth being upvoted at all. To make the point clear: I personally like the second sentence more than the first one. So, what is user _foo_'s reason to prefer the first one? Is it a matter of right or wrong? Of style? Of sound? Or is it really only because **he** imagines dogs? In the latter case, this subjective answer is not good.

Comment: i would say it would be fine if the reason would something like "as this is more used" or "there is no missinterpretation of the sentence"

Answer (score 0):

> Meine Eltern kommen aus Afghanistan.

All the other suggestion sound strange or complicated from a native speakers perspective.

Comment: _"Meine Eltern sind Afghanen."_ What is so complicated in this sentence?

Comment: It sounds artificial if used in the given context, because it stresses that the parents are (still) afghan citizens. In general it is enough to say the country of origin if being asked "Woher kommen deine Eltern?".

Comment: Afghane can also mean the dog breed. Therefore I'd prefer "... aus Afghanistan". Same is true for Weimarer and Weimaraner, the former is a person, the latter a dog.